Greedy Algorithm to Minimize Color Transitions in a Directed Acyclic Graph
I am working with a directed acyclic graph (DAG) where:

Some nodes are already assigned a color (e.g., red).
Some nodes are colorless and can optionally be assigned a color.
The input and output nodes are colorless and cannot have a color.
A node with an existing color cannot change its color.

The goal is to suggest colors for each colorless node (or leave it colorless) such that the number of transitions is minimized.
A transition is defined as:
An edge where the source and target nodes have different colors.
An edge where one node has a color, and the other node is colorless (and vice versa).
EDIT:
After getting some comments I will try to explain myself a bit better:
The graph is directed but has no circles, so a node might have multiple successors and predecessors, so if node has multiple predecessors, but all has same common predecessor, it's better to make all with same color if possible, it will reduce the number of transitions by |num_of_preds - 1| and if several nodes has specific color, it might affect the number of transitions dramatically.
I don't sure if a greedy algorithm is the best here, I'm open for suggestions and any help is appreciated.

You prefer to have adjacent nodes the same color?  ( Usually the opposite is wanted )

Note that the edge direction doesn't matter, so your graph is effectively undirected and can have undirected cycles.  The problem is multi-way min cut, which is quite hard: https://courses.grainger.illinois.edu/cs598csc/sp2009/lectures/lecture_7.pdf

Yes I prefer to have adjacent nodes the same color.

What exactly is your question?

What is the function of "input" and "output" nodes? It seems not relevant, except that there are two designated nodes that cannot get a color. Other than that, they seem to serve no purpose. Unless maybe you look for minimising the transitions only on a (selected) path from input to output node, ignoring transitions that are not on that path. But this is nowhere stated in your post. This question is not clear.

Count the number of pre-assigned nodes with each color.
Select the color that is assigned to most.
Color all the unassigned nodes, except input and output, with the selected color.
As @trincot carefully points out this algorithm will not guarantee an optimal solution in every case.  In compensation, it is blindingly fast. In the example you mention it will reach the optimal solution

Usually,  on my application I have up to one color so by using your suggestion I will have all the nodes with same colors (except input and outputs). So basically if a red node has one input and one output, two transitions in total, and by coloring all the graph the number of transitions can be bigger.

If all the nodes are the same color, the only 'transitions' ( by your definition: A transition is defined as: An edge where the source and target nodes have different colors.  ) are leaving inputs and entering outputs.  So minimum transistions.  So optimal result.

" the number of transitions can be bigger."  Of course there can be more transmissions, but you want to minimize the transitions - the point is the number of transitions cannot be less.

This will not always lead to an optimal solution.

@trincot The OP asked for a greedy algorithm.  Such algorithms usually do not guarantee an optimal solution.  In the example OP describes in the comment, the optimal solution is found.
